# Font is available, but not found by xeLaTeX

Tags: errors, xetex, fontspec

I am experimenting with a CV template, which uses the Lato fonts.  On my Linux system, they are in the `/usr/share/fonts/TTF` directory, and the command `fc-list | grep -i lato` shows them.  And they have the same ownership and permissions as all other TTF fonts.  But the command

```
\setmainfont[...]{Lato-Lig}
```

in xelatex, produces an error that the font cannot be found. I'm using TeXLive 2015.  This should be a very simple matter, and in fact I've got to where I am now by following other helpful hints, but I still don't seem to make that font available to xelatex.  Any advice would be welcome!

Answer (score 3):

You're not giving people much to go on. This works for me (never used the font before):

```
% NOTE: TL2016, not TL2015 
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}% XeTeX
\setmainfont{Lato}[
  Path = /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/fonts/truetype/public/lato/ ,
  Extension       =  .ttf ,
  UprightFont     =  Lato-Lig    ,
  ItalicFont      =  Lato-LigIta ,
  BoldFont        =  Lato-Bol    , % if using Lato-Lig for regular font; then maybe Lato-Reg would be better for the 'bold'....
  BoldItalicFont  =  Lato-BolIta ,
]
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand\ftest{0123456789.!?<>()[]*\&\%\$\#@
\lipsum[1]}

\begin{document}

\ftest

{\itshape \ftest}

{\bfseries \ftest}

{\bfseries\itshape \ftest}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Note: strictly speaking, the `PATH` declaration is not needed. But maybe it is in other cases.

Comment: Thank you - this gets me halfway there.  I'm trying to compile a document which uses this font, and your example works, as does a test one of mine.  But the document I have hiccups on lines like `\fontspec{Lato-Hai}\selectfont #1` which I would have thought would be fine.

Comment: @Alasdair - if `\fontspec{Lato-Lig}` (very similar to `\setmainfont{Lato-Lig}`) wasn't working on your system before, why would you expect `\fontspec{Lato-Hai}` to work? Incidentally, the use of the low-level `\fontspec` macro is deprecated. You should probably be using something like `\newfontfamily` instead. Do consult the well-written and very throrough user guide of the `fontspec` package for more information on methods for loading fonts.

Comment: @Alasdair -- unless we work from a common `.tex` file we are going to waste a lot of time mucking around in the comments. It really is better to post a complete, but [minimal example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/8528) (or see [here](http://www.tex.ac.uk/cgi-bin/texfaq2html?label=minxampl)) when you're asking a question.  (I'd also second Mico's comment.)

Comment: Thank you all; I'll keep fiddling, but before I ask again I'll construct a minimal example - which I, errr, should have done at the start!